# Keep mouse pointer busy while launching a script

Tags: cursor, .desktop

I have a Windows program which is run via wine. Since it needs a couple steps of preparation, I created a script `app.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
do-something
do-something-else
wine app.exe
```

Then I added the app to the menu. The desktop file is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=/path/to/icons
Name=app
Exec=sh -c "/path/to/app.sh"
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
```

In this case it takes a while until the window is displayed. I'd like the mouse pointer to stay busy until the window is created. Is it possible to do it somehow?

Comment: This is normally done by adding [`StartupNotify=true`](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/startup-notification.html.en) to your launcher provided your application/script supports [_startup notification_](http://standards.freedesktop.org/startup-notification-spec/startup-notification-latest.txt).